# HTTPS breaking embedded PDF

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, https

I just switched to HTTPS on my website. I had been displaying a locally hosted PDF via an iframe; the iframe displays a small html file with the PDF embedded (as an object) in it. However, the PDF is no longer displaying. I can navigate to the PDF & it displays just fine but does not display when I load the html page. What can I do to make the PDF display?

iframe

```
<iframe src="/updates/update.htm" width="100%" height="800px"
marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

update.htm

```
<html>
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom-styles.css">
</style>
</header>

<body>
<object src="update.pdf"
type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px"><div id="show-text">
<p>It appears your web browser is not configured to display PDF files.</p>
<p><a href='update.pdf'>Click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>
</div>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

custom-styles.css

```
#show-text {
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 15%;
background: #D1D1D1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shot in the dark here, but are you sure that `"/updates/update.htm"` is the right path? If your page is `www.site.com/something/index.php` and you use that path, the browser will look for `www.site.com/something/updates/update.htm`. Perhaps you want `www.site.com/updates/update.htm`. Maybe you need a relative path like `"../updates/update.htm"`

**UPDATE**
Try `<object data="update.pdf">`. The `<embed>` tag uses `scr=`; `<object>` uses `data=` according to w3schools.

Comment: I've double checked but it appears that the iframe is not the source of the problem. I changed the URL from relative to static, but the PDF still fails to show. When I navigate to the page the iframe is pointed at, I get a completely blank page with no PDF.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason <object src= worked when the page was served over http but does not work over https. Changing src= to data= fixed it.